# Mongoose create() resolved before async middleware is finished

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: string,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: string,
    required: true
  },
    authtokens: {
        type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'AuthToken' }]
    }
});

//hashing a password before saving it to the database
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.gensalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, null, function (err, hash){
                if (err) return next(err);
                this.password = hash;
                console.log('user.password ', this.password);
                next();
            });
        });
    } else next();
});
```

I call this from a controller:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
    AuthToken = mongoose.model('AuthToken');

exports.createUser = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.email && req.body.password && req.body.passwordConf) {
        var userData = {
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            passwordConf: req.body.passwordConf
        };
        //use schema.create to insert data into the db
        User.create(userData, function (err, user) {
            console.log('user created ', user.password);
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res.redirect('/profile');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var err = new Error("Missing parameters");
        err.status = 400;
        next(err);
    }
};
```

When a `createUser` is called with email `user@email.com`, password `password`, I get the output:

```
user.password  $2a$10$wO.6TPUm5b1j6lvHdCi/JOTeEXHWhYernWU.ZzA3hfYhyWoOeugcq
user created  password
```

Also, looking directly in the database, I see this user with plain text password -> `password`.

Why is user having plaintext password in the database. How can I store the hash instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you forgot you were going into a callback which has a different functional scope and you're still referring to `this`, which is at that time not actually the "model" instance.

To correct this, take a copy of `this` before you do anything like launching another function with a callback:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;              // keep a copy
  if (this.isNew) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt) {
      if (err) next(err);
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) next(err);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

An alternate approach of course is to modernize things and use `Promise` results with `async/await`. The [`bcrypt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) library which is actually the "core" and not a fork does this right out of the box:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  if (this.isNew) {
    let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    let hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    this.password = hash;
  }
});
```

Aside from the modern approach being generally cleaner code, you also don't need to change the scope of `this` since we don't "dive in" to another function call. Everything gets changed in the same scope, and of course awaits the async calls before continuing.

#### Full Example - Callback

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/crypto';

var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;          // keep a copy
  if (this.isNew) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt) {
      if (err) next(err);
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) next(err);
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  }
});

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    await User.create({ email: 'ted@example.com', password: 'password' });

    let result = await User.findOne();
    log(result);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }


})()
```

#### Full Example - Promise async/await

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/crypto';

var userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function() {
  if (this.isNew) {
    let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    let hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    this.password = hash;
  }
});

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    await User.create({ email: 'ted@example.com', password: 'password' });

    let result = await User.findOne();
    log(result);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }


})()
```

Both show the password correctly encrypted, since we actually set the value in the model instance:

```
{
  "_id": "5aec65f4853eed12050db4d9",
  "email": "ted@example.com",
  "password": "$2b$10$qAovc0m0VtmtpLg7CRZmcOXPDNi.2WbPjSFkfxSUqh8Pu5lyN4p7G",
  "__v": 0
}
```